# Javascript bringing specific div of external file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using fancybox to load a video within iframe. And i need to create one .php file for each video. Is it possible to put all videos in same file and bring only a specific div where video are and i want?

```
$(".iframe").fancybox({
    'beforeLoad' : function(){
    var url= $(this.element).data("href");
    this.href = baseURL+'assets/media/mp4/'+url+'.php'
    }
});
```

MY external divs

```
<div id="MBHD0790-04"> 
    <video>
        <source src="~source~/MBHD0790-04.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div id="MBHD0790-03">
    <video>
        <source src="~source~/MBHD0790-03.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div id="MBHD0790-02"> 
    <video>    
        <source src="~source~/MBHD0790-02.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

My VIEW

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-href="MBHD0790-04" id="MBHD0790-04" class="iframe">
    GETVIDEO
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
this.href = baseURL+'assets/media/mp4/'+videoid+'.php'
```

Do this:

```
this.href = baseURL+'assets/media/mp4/video.php?videoId='+videoid
```

Then all you need to create is a video.php file that would display the appropriate HTML. The most simple example:

```
<?php
    switch ($_GET['videoId'])
    {
         case 'one':
             echo '<div>content of video div with id=one</div>';
             break;
         case 'two':
             echo '<div>content of video div with id=two</div>';
             break;
         ...
    }
?>
```

This could obviously be optimized with loops, arrays etc.

Comment: Almost there. fancybox doesnt load correctly. Using .get or .load will not work better? I dont know how to filter using them. btw using case i cant load external .js files- it will be necessary.

Comment: You can load external js files. If not - you're doing something wrong. You can just add them before the entire switch statement or in "case" statements if those files have to be different for every video.